# Как изменить пагинацию Ajax на CMS Opencart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой! Отзовитесь. 
Сайт sovamall.com.ua
Скачивал тему kavir2.demo.towerthemes.com 
Вместе с темой достались категории AJAX. 
Вот с ними теперь постоянные проблемы. 
Сейчас основная проблема в том что не запоминается предыдущая категория. 
К примеру я перешел на 2-рую страницу категорий потом зашел на любой товар, он мне не понравился, я нажимаю стрелку возврата на предыдущую страницу, и попадаю снова на 1 страницу категорий. 
А по логике я должен был вернуться на 2 страницу. 
Если их отключаешь то все слетает стили итд. Но стили это бог с ним, главное что перестает работать переключение страниц. 
При попытке переключить страницу вываливает код.

Это возможно изменить малой кровью?

Comment: Вопрос стал по новому)
Есть два файла шаблона категорий.
В одном работает а в другом не работает пагинация(
Не работает как раз в нужном мне

Comment: Ссылка на 2 файла
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bFxCshg7heXjVTVsrDfbhSFhKMuigxrs

Answer (score 0):

Вы вряд ли получите ответ с рецептом. Вопрос касается реализации конкретного шаблона OC, сама же cms не при делах. Тут необходимо вгрызаться в шаблон и обрабатывать напильником под ваши нужды. Начните с вопроса разработчикам шаблона. Или наймите специалистов для решения вашей проблемы.

А в общем - смотрите в файлах плагина, как аякс-пагинация запрашивает выборку. Если поймёте, то есть шанс зацепится за это, сохраняя состояния выборки (или url с параметрами), например, в localStorage и далее проверять хранилище при каждом запросе страницы, вытаскивать и делать принудительный ajax-запрос c необходимыми параметрами.

Удачи.

Comment: Вопрос стал по новому) Есть два файла шаблона категорий. В одном работает а в другом не работает пагинация( Не работает как раз в нужном мне

Ссылка на 2 файла drive.google.com/open?id=1bFxCshg7heXjVTVsrDfbhSFhKMuigxrs